# Create mixed orientation PDFs in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Part of my application needs to create PDF reports with charts and tables. Some of the tables are quite wide, and so i think it would be best if they were outputted on separate landscape orientated pages, while the rest of the PDF is in portrait orientation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to create PDF documents in (ASP).NET.
Before adding a page, you can define its orientation:

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4);
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, output);
pdfDocument.Open();
for (int i = 0; i < pages.Length; i++)
{
    pdfDocument.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate()); //landscape
    //doc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4); // default
    pdfDocument.NewPage();
}
```

Namespaces:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

For more information about iTextSharp, here are a few tutorials:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/80/create-pdfs-in-asp-net-getting-started-with-itextsharp

If you want to use your application in a commercial context, make sure your install the [LGPL version of iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/).